# How do I write a script to automatically compile and install all Moksha modules?

Tags: shell-script, find, compiling, for

I have [this](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/moksha-modules-extra/) repository cloned on my Sabayon machine, what I would like to do is write a script that will change into each directory of this repo (just the top-level directories, not directories inside these directories) and run `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install`. I was thinking that maybe this script will do what I want:

```
for i in `find . -type d`
do
  pushd $i
  ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
  popd
done
```

but, the only problem is that `find . -type d` shows every directory within this repo, including directories within directories (e.g., it shows `tclock/images`, that is the `images` directory, within the `tclock` directory), when I want just top-level directories (or `tclock` in the previous example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this works:

```
for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;`
do
  pushd $i
    ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
  popd
done
```

although, some odd error messages pop out from this, so if anyone has a better answer I will be more than willing to accept it.